# How Can I Find Certificate in Web Hosting -> Certificates

Tags: wcf, certificate, x509certificate

We have our certificate saved under Certificates (Local Machine) -> Web Hosting -> Certificates. Can anyone give me an idea on how to reference that on my WCF's web.config?